# Cannot reset Chrome (Mac)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google, web-browser

I've been getting a problem with Chrome where it keeps crashing when I try to refresh a web page. Bear in mind this only appears to happen on a local .html file that I'm building.

So I tried to reset Chrome through it's settings menu, but it doesn't appear to work. I just get the spinning circle which never ends, and then I have to force quit.

On restarting Chrome, it looks like 'some' of it has been reset (e.g. I have to log back in to websites) but I still have things such as my history and bookmarks.

Does anyone know another way I can reset it? Perhaps by just removing a folder from my computer?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: thanks, have just given that a go so hopefully it fixes it!